# load elements from another page with attribute greater than number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting a 'recent' page for one of my websites. I want to load all elements with class="Article" *and* some other attribute (such as time) which has an integer value greater than a number.

I've looked around and I know how to load selected elements with a certain id from another page, but I want to further filter those results down by date. The date will be time in seconds from Jan 1st 1970.

Comment: *..all elements with id="Article"* - Only a single element should have a unique `id`, use `class` for many elements.

Comment: add another selector to your filter method. 

//if id="Article" and time < desired age

For any more specifics you would need to post some code of your current filter method and how the time is saved. (+1 on the id comment from Spencer)

Comment: Ah figured it out. The simplicity is pretty stupid and I feel dumb asking, but whatever. I'll have to answer my own question when I have time.